# Weblogic fails when launched from IntelliJ Idea: Error: Could not find or load main class :

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic12c

I was hoping to get help with getting IntelliJ Idea to launch Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0. It was working fine until my project upgraded it's version of Java from 1.7 to 1.8.  The server and application works fine when being started from the Weblogic scripts, but I am unable to debug this way. Note I can't launch the server even with nothing set up to deploy.  Other members of my team were able to upgrade just fine without an issue like this, so it's not the code base. I've upgraded the project's version in IntelliJ and that did not work.  Here is the exception from the IntelliJ log, but it's not helpful.

```
WARN - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - Unable to ping server at localhost:7001 
2018-03-02 08:42:41,600 [ 113611]   WARN - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - Unable to ping server at localhost:7001 
2018-03-02 08:42:41,601 [ 113612]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group JavaEE is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:65)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:50)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:82)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:87)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.createConnectErrorNotification(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:356)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl$ConnectLogger.reportError(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:542)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.disconnect(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:183)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerConnector$1.processTerminated(JavaeeServerConnector.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper$2.processTerminated(J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$4.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$3.run(ProcessHandler.java:184)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:260)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:165)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:161)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:192)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(OSProcessHandler.java:92)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.java:89)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:155)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:140)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor$1.run(ProcessWaitFor.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-03-02 08:43:46,027 [ 178038]   WARN - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - Unable to ping server at localhost:7001 
2018-03-02 08:43:46,027 [ 178038]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group JavaEE is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:65)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:50)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:82)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:87)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.createConnectErrorNotification(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:356)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl$ConnectLogger.reportError(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:542)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.disconnect(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:183)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerConnector$1.processTerminated(JavaeeServerConnector.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper$2.processTerminated(J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$4.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$3.run(ProcessHandler.java:184)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:260)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:165)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:161)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:192)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(OSProcessHandler.java:92)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.java:89)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:155)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:140)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor$1.run(ProcessWaitFor.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the console, I see this:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\project\startWebLogic.cmd
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Odracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\wljmxclient.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\weblogicIntegration\lib\weblogicIntegration.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-impl.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\lib\openapi.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\weblogicIntegration\lib\specifics\weblogicSpecifics.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 50145 com.intellij.javaee.weblogic.agent.WebLogicAgent9
[2018-03-02 09:06:03,645] Artifact project3:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server http port: 7001
[2018-03-02 09:06:03,645] Artifact project2:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
java version "1.8.0_162"
[2018-03-02 09:06:03,646] Artifact project1:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: : -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
.
CLASSPATH=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\lib\ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\com.oracle.cie.config-wls-online_8.1.0.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derby.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\bin;C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\ICLSCL~1\;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\ICLSCL~1\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\INTEL(~1\DAL;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(~3\DAL;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\INTEL(~1\IPT;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(~3\IPT;C:\PROGRA~1\TORTOI~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd;C:\PROGRA~1\Maven\APACHE~1.0\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\bin;C:\HASHIC~1\Vagrant\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\OpenSSH\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\;C:\Users\jorell\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\bin\java -server   : -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54748,suspend=y,server=n  -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\endorsed  -da -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dlog4j.configuration=file:var/project/log4j2.xml    weblogic.Server
Error: Could not find or load main class :
Disconnected from server
```

Here is the full IntelliJ Log as requested

```
2018-03-09 08:34:29,717 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -
------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED   
------------------------------------------------------ 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,730 [     13]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI -   
User scale factor: 1.0 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,730 [     13]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI -   
System scale factor: 1.0 (IDE-managed HiDPI) 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,739 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -  
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-173.4548.28, 29 Jan 2018 17:29) 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,739 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -  
OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,739 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -  
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b11 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,741 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -   
JVM: 25.152-b11 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,744 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 
JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea 
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow 
-Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4\bin
\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ 
IDEA 2017.3.4\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true 
-Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2017.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\jorell
\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\jorell
\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,746 [     29]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 
ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@ea1ab27[Running, 
parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, 
submissions = 0] 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,747 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 
ext: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4\jre64\lib\ext: 
[access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, 
localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, 
sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,747 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 
JNU charset: Cp1252 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,781 [     64]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 
JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 34 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:29,783 [     66]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - 
Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2018-03-09 08:34:31,623 [   1906]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -  
130 plugins initialized in 1101 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:31,640 [   1923]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 
Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), Android Support (10.2.3), AngularJS 
(173.4548.28), Ant Support (1.0), Application Servers View (0.2.0), AspectJ 
Support (1.2), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CFML Support (3.53), CSS Support 
(173.4548.28), CVS Integration (11), Cloud Foundry integration (1.0), 
CloudBees integration (1.0), CoffeeScript (2.0), Copyright (8.1), Coverage 
(173.4548.28), Cucumber for Groovy (999.999), Cucumber for Java (999.999), 
DSM Analysis (1.0.0), Database Tools and SQL (173.4548.28), Eclipse 
Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (173.4548.28), Emma (173.4548.28), 
Flash/Flex Support (173.4548.28), FreeMarker support (1.0), GWT Support 
(1.0), Geronimo Integration (1.0), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration 
(8.1), GitHub (173.4548.28), GlassFish Integration (1.0), Google App Engine 
Integration (1.1.4), Gradle (173.4548.28), Grails (9.0), Groovy (9.0), 
Guice (8.0), HTML Tools (2.0), Haml (173.4548.28), Heroku integration 
(173.4548.28), Hibernate Support (1.0), I18n for Java (173.4548.28), IDE 
Settings Sync (173.4548.28), IDEA CORE (173.4548.28), IntelliLang (8.0), 
J2ME (1.0), JBoss Arquillian Support (1.0), JBoss Drools Support (1.0), 
JBoss Frameworks Base Support (1.0), JBoss Integration (1.0), JBoss Seam 
Pageflow Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Pages Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Support 
(1.0), JBoss jBPM (2.0.0), JSR45 Integration (1.0), JUnit (1.0), Java 
Bytecode Decompiler (173.4548.28), Java EE: Batch Applications (1.0), Java 
EE: Bean Validation Support (1.1), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency 
Injection (1.1), Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets (1.0), Java EE: JMS, JSON 
Processing, Concurrency, Transaction  (1.0), Java EE: Java Server Faces 
(2.2.X.), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (1.0), Java EE: Web 
Services (JAX-WS) (1.9), Java EE: WebSockets (1.0), Java Server Pages (JSP) 
Integration (1.0), Java Stream Debugger (173.4548.28), JavaFX (1.0), 
JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), 
JavaScript Support (1.0), Jetty Integration (1.0), Kotlin (1.2.10-release-
IJ2017.3-1), Less support (173.4548.28), Markdown support (173.4548.28), 
Maven Integration (173.4548.28), Maven Integration Extension (173.4548.28), 
Mercurial Integration (10.0), OpenShift integration (1.0), Osmorc (1.4.11), 
Perforce Integration (2.0), Persistence Frameworks Support (1.0), 
Playframework Support (1.0), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support 
(173.4548.28), QuirksMode (173.4548.28), REST Client (173.4548.28), 
Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), Resin Integration (8.1), SSH 
Remote Run (0.1), Sass support (173.4548.28), Settings Repository 
(173.4548.28), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (1.0), Spring Batch (1.0), Spring Boot 
(1.0), Spring Data (1.0), Spring Integration Patterns (1.0), Spring MVC 
(1.0), Spring OSGi (1.0), Spring Security (1.0), Spring Support (1.0), 
Spring Web Flow (1.0), Spring Web Services (1.0), Spring WebSocket (1.0), 
Spy-js (173.4548.28), Struts 1.x (2.0), Struts 2 (1.0), Stylus support 
(999.999), Subversion Integration (1.1), TFS Integration (999.999), 
Tapestry support (1.0), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J 
(8.0), Thymeleaf (1.0), Time Tracking (1.0), Tomcat and TomEE Integration 
(1.0), UI Designer (173.4548.28), UML Support (1.0), Vaadin Support (1.0), 
Velocity support (1.0), W3C Validators (2.0), WebLogic Integration (1.0), 
WebSphere Integration (1.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger 
(1.4), YAML (173.4548.28), ZKM-Unscramble (1.0), dmServer Support (0.9.5), 
tslint (173.4548.28) 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,200 [   3483]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager -   
=== Start.updateInitStatus === 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,204 [   3487]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - 
=== Start: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,204 [   3487]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus === 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,246 [   3529]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,288 [   3571]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,350 [   3633]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,366 [   3649]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2018-03-09 08:34:33,847 [   4130]   INFO - .cloudConfig.CloudConfigClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files === 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,038 [   4321]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=0.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,327 [   4610]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus.value: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,397 [   4680]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity@1b915f3a 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,547 [   4830]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,588 [   4871]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,831 [   5114]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:198 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,839 [   5122]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:7 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,875 [   5158]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:30 
2018-03-09 08:34:34,875 [   5158]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2018-03-09 08:34:35,374 [   5657]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 98 application components initialized in 4856ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:35,388 [   5671]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 6600 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:36,482 [   6765]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1643 
2018-03-09 08:34:36,741 [   7024]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:258 
2018-03-09 08:34:36,864 [   7147]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2018-03-09 08:34:37,256 [   7539]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@3babebcd 
2018-03-09 08:34:37,257 [   7540]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2018-03-09 08:34:37,271 [   7554]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2018-03-09 08:34:37,274 [   7557]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Users/jorell/gitlab/project] 
2018-03-09 08:34:38,959 [   9242]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 177 project components initialized in 2883 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:39,474 [   9757]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@56f19300 
 2018-03-09 08:34:39,650 [   9933]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 36 module(s) loaded in 690 ms 
 2018-03-09 08:34:39,956 [  10239]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@b9b8dc3 
 2018-03-09 08:34:39,969 [  10252]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2018-03-09 08:34:40,237 [  10520]   WARN - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
2018-03-09 08:34:41,135 [  11418]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - backward reference index version differ due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException 
2018-03-09 08:34:41,465 [  11748]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 22 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:42,065 [  12348]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 593ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-03-09 08:34:42,382 [  12665]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [] using cp:  
2018-03-09 08:34:42,387 [  12670]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider KotlinCompilerScriptTemplatesSettings is invalid:  
2018-03-09 08:34:42,423 [  12706]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Kotlin DSL is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2018-03-09 08:34:42,424 [  12707]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Kotlin DSL is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2018-03-09 08:34:42,424 [  12707]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Script Kotlin is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2018-03-09 08:34:42,424 [  12707]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [kotlin.script.templates.standard.ScriptTemplateWithArgs] using cp:  
2018-03-09 08:34:43,909 [  14192]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OpenFilesActivity run in 2473ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-03-09 08:34:44,080 [  14363]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 2687ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/3 sluggish 
2018-03-09 08:34:44,305 [  14588]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.update create === 
2018-03-09 08:34:44,306 [  14589]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateInitStatus === 
2018-03-09 08:34:44,828 [  15111]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 304 ms spent to cache options in application 
 2018-03-09 08:34:44,900 [  15183]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/jorell/gitlab/project/maven-project/project/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2018-03-09 08:34:45,287 [  15570]   INFO -                git4idea.GitVcs - Git version: 2.13.3.0 (CYGWIN) 
2018-03-09 08:34:45,520 [  15803]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Users/jorell/gitlab/project] 
2018-03-09 08:34:46,638 [  16921]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 10763 ms 
2018-03-09 08:34:49,954 [  20237]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 7888ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 5/8 sluggish, 1/8 very slow 
2018-03-09 08:34:50,396 [  20679]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start another widget: com.intellij.cloudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager$InfoComponent@2f6d50d1 === 
2018-03-09 08:34:51,313 [  21596]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 202 ms spent to cache options in project 
2018-03-09 08:34:53,789 [  24072]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - HTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5.rnc 
2018-03-09 08:34:53,790 [  24073]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - XHTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/xhtml5.rnc 
2018-03-09 08:34:53,790 [  24073]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - CHARS_DTD_LOCATION = C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5chars.ent 
2018-03-09 08:35:02,026 [  32309]   WARN - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - Unable to ping server at localhost:7001 
2018-03-09 08:35:32,164 [  62447]   WARN - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - Unable to ping server at localhost:7001 
2018-03-09 08:35:32,166 [  62449]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group JavaEE is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
 at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:65)
at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:50)
at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:82)
at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:87)
at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.createConnectErrorNotification(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:357)
at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl$ConnectLogger.lambda$reportError$0(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:544)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.a(LaterInvocator.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.j(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to share full idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: y.bedrov I added the full log as requested to the original post.  Thanks for replying!